# Jinja + Vue webpack templates trouble

Tags: python, flask, vue.js, jinja2

I have some troubles. I want to use Flask with Vue.js. So my problem is in Jinja templates (yeah, I made custom templates and I will show it later). I don't know where my problem is, so I will show my actions step by step.
 First of all I initialize my Vue project:

```
vue init webpack myproject
cd myproject
npm install
```

So, i change Jinja template like this:

```
class CustomFlask(Flask):

  jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
  jinja_options.update(dict(
      block_start_string='%%',
      block_end_string='%%',
      variable_start_string='%',
      variable_end_string='%',
      comment_start_string='%#',
      comment_end_string='%#',
  ))


app = CustomFlask(__name__)
```

And the next step is to paste some variable into **App.vue** file: %name% (for example) 
After that I build Vue project with command:

```
npm run build
```

In "dist" folder I have **index.html** and in this folder I put my **App.py**. This file I put in the "templates" folder of the same directory and finall step is open page in Flask app:

```
@app.route('/')
def show_index_page():
    return render_template('index.html',name='MyNAME')
```

But the result on my screen when I start server is:
"%name%" instead of "MyNAME". 
Help me, please. Don't know where the mistake is

Comment: Maybe I should use any webpack or install some special package for python?